# HTML Img failing to show. Using WAMP server + CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, wamp

So this is the code of the view. For some reason the imagine does not show. Var_dumping $oProduct->img_path returns (I modified these paths for testing purposes , since I'm working with more db entries):

`'W:/wamp/www/repos/adicris/imgs/products/logo.jpg' (one element)`
`'imgs/products/logo.jpg' (some other element)`

`'/imgs/products/logo.jpg'  (some other element)`

adicris is the folder containing the entire project.

So as you can see I tried giving it the full path and the relative path , with no success.

PS: The picture name is spelled correctly , it does allow for jpg and it is in the right folder.

```
    <?php foreach ($aProducts->result() as $oProduct): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$oProduct->pid?></td>
            <td><?=$oProduct->name?></td>
            <td><img scr=<?=$oProduct->img_path?>></td>
            <td><?=$oProduct->price?></td>
            <td><?=$oProduct->description?></td>
            <td><?=$oProduct->type_name?></td>
        </tr>           
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

I also tried this in the img line:

```
   <td><img scr="<?=base_url()?><?=$oProduct->img_path?>></td>
```

Fails for all entries regardless of img_path form.

Comment: missing " try `<img scr="<?=base_url()?><?php echo $oProduct->img_path?>">`

Comment: I think you'll find it's `src`.

Comment: I cannot believe I spent two hours on this not realizing I've written scr instead of src.

You should leave you're adress , I'll send you a beer over mail ,hahah.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The smallest things. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><img src="<?=base_url()?><?=$oProduct->img_path?>"></td>
         ^^^ Not scr.
```

Don't forget the quotes for your tag attributes either. Whilst it works in most browsers, it's not valid.